# New Linkedin API for mobile (android)

Tags: android, mobile, linkedin-api, android-applicationinfo

I was going through the new Linkedin Android SDK . I believe that for any app that is going to use the SDK, having the Linkedin app on the android phone is mandatory.Is this understanding correct? If not, then what is the way out?

Comment: first of all you need to implement the LinkedIn SDK into your application and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seems correct according to the [official documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk).
One way to play around it could be to check if the LinkedIn application is installed and if not use an Intent to send the user to the Play store for him to install it.

Comment: Thanks Bhullnatik for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The official LinkedIn android application is required to be installed to facilitate any of the functionality provided by the SDK.

It has capabilities built into it to handle all client states gracefully (e.g. no LinkedIn app installed, app installed but user not logged in, app installed and user logged in, etc.)

Additional info can be found in LinkedIn's docs here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth#ux

Comment: Thanks Justin for the clarification!